# How to get ApexLogs in an action called from LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, debug-logs, apex-debugger

I would like to know how to obtain the data that my apex method is generating step by step, system debugs. I have not seen any documentation on the internet which has some information of what I need.

In aura it's easy, you open the developer console and you get all the apexlogs in the "log section".

I only found examples for javascript on the internet and not for apex

Thank you.

EDIT:

```
validarContratoJS(){

this.contract = this.getSObject(this.contract);
this.camposFormularioWrapper = { tipoConfiguracion : 'validarContrato', contrato : this.contract };

validarContrato({camposFormulario: this.camposFormularioWrapper })
    .then(result => { 
        if(!result.success){
            console.log('error: '+ JSON.stringify(result));
            this.contratoValido = true;
            this.contratoCortable = result.contratoCortable;
            console.log('codigo tipo contrato: '+this.contract.ATN_Codigo_Tipo_Contrato__c);
            this.codTipoContrato = this.contract.contratoCortableATN_Codigo_Tipo_Contrato__c;

        if(this.contratoValido && result.fechaVencimientoProducto){
            this.fechaVencimientoProducto = true;
        }
        if(this.contratoValido && result.solicitudModificado){
            this.solicitudModificado = true;
            //falta poner disabled boton modificacion economica
            //falta poner disabled boton tecnicas siempre que la linea negocio sea distinto de Gas
        }
        this.spinner = false;
        console.log('he puesto el spinner a false');
    }else{
        this.spinner = false;
        this.mensajeError = result.mensaje;
        this.contratoValido = false;
        console.log('mensajeError pero bien: '+this.mensajeError);
    }
})
.catch(error => { 
  console.log('Error mensaje: '+JSON.stringify(error));
  let message = 'Unknown error';
        if (Array.isArray(error.body)) {
            message = error.body.map(e => e.message).join(', ');
        } else if (typeof error.body.message === 'string') {
            message = error.body.message;
        }
        console.log('Error mensaje detallado: '+message);
});}
```

This javascript function calls the apex method "validarContrato", but the console does not throw any debug log to know why it has returned the value in one way or another.

Comment: I certainly wish to help you but I am not sure what you are asking. Can I suggest a little code examples of your LWC and/or Apex Class. Every custom apex call creates a log that you can find in salesforce dev console.

Comment: It goes under `aura` logs in developer console.

Comment: LWC does not create any debug logging in the developer console. I am currently migrating an aura component to LWC. the component the first thing it does is validate the contract record. I update the post with the code

Comment: LWC does not create debug logging as it's a web component framework for salesforce platform (front end) You need  to debug using chrome or browser supported debug tool like debugging client side JS.

Comment: the aura component gives me a result and LWC another with the same data and the same method.

Do you mean that with LWC I cannot obtain for example system debugs or any debug log ?,

It doesn't make sense yet to migrate to web component then.

Comment: can you provide english code and apex class in English?

Comment: The aura component and LWC component differs and there are performance effeciencies achieved due to caching at client side. The render and re-render mechanism is different.  LWC leverages ES6 constructs  like templates, custom elements. If you  are designing the LWC component with your requirements and design considerations it offer greater flexibility and performance over Aura component. The log at server can be collected and referenced in both LWC, aura.